# Gatsby Build Error: WebpackError: TypeError: apiFn is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I've got both dynamic and static markdown pages on this site, and this error is surprisingly thrown for a blog post page (just markdown):

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 3.005s

 ERROR #95313  HTML.COMPILATION

Building static HTML failed for path "/blog/my-blog-page/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  74 |
  75 |     try {
> 76 |       const result = apiFn(args, plugin.options)
     |                      ^
  77 |
  78 |       if (result && argTransform) {
  79 |         args = argTransform({ args, result })


  WebpackError: TypeError: apiFn is not a function
  
  - api-runner-ssr.js:76 
    my-project/.cache/api-runner-ssr.js:76:22
  
  - api-runner-ssr.js:69 
    my-project/.cache/api-runner-ssr.js:69:11
  
  - static-entry.js:272 
    my-project/.cache/static-entry.js:272:16
  
  - index.js:93 
    [my-project]/[query-string]/index.js:93:1
```

After reading the [Gatsby Debugging HTML Builds documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#ssr-during-gatsby-develop) and adding:

```js
flags: {
  DEV_SSR: true
},
```

to my `gatsby-config.js` I see the following:

```
Failed to Server Render (SSR)
Error message:
TypeError: apiFn is not a function

File:
node_modules/webidl-conversions/lib/index.js:178:1

Stack:
WebpackError: TypeError: apiFn is not a function
    at my-project/node_modules/webidl-conversions/lib/index.js:178:1
    at my-project/node_modules/webidl-conversions/lib/index.js:173:1
    at my-project/.cache/ssr-develop-static-entry.js:275:8
    at my-project/src/hooks/useIsMarketOpen.ts:30:7
    at my-project/.cache/ssr-develop-static-entry.js:330:19
    at my-project/.cache/caches/gatsby-plugin-offline/app-shell.js:12:3
```

So it looks like an issue with this `webidl-conversions` package.

Interestingly the site runs fine in development mode, I can even visit that blog page without any issues.

EDIT: Did some package cleanups and upgrades, still getting this error, though now it is in a different place:

```
Failed to Server Render (SSR)
Error message:
TypeError: apiFn is not a function

File:
node_modules/common-tags/es/splitStringTransformer/index.js:3:1

Stack:
WebpackError: TypeError: apiFn is not a function
    at my-project/node_modules/common-tags/es/splitStringTransformer/index.js:3:1
    at my-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28587:1
    at my-project/node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/DefaultHttpClient.js:18:1
    at my-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28654:1
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working. Turns out it had nothing to do with any libraries, packages, or any of my own source code. The problem was that I had modified my `gatsby-ssr.js` to this:

```js
const wrapWithProvider = require('./wrap-with-provider')

exports.wrapRootElement = wrapWithProvider
```

Apparently, Gatsby doesn't like this syntax `exports.wrapRootElement = wrapWithProvider`. Following more examples [from the SSR documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#wrapRootElement), I realized I could get rid of the `wrap-with-provider.jsx` completely (a legacy Gatsby pattern), and do this:

```js
const React = require('react')
const { Provider } = require('react-redux')
const { store, persistor } = require('./src/store/index')
const { PersistGate } = require('redux-persist/integration/react')

exports.wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        {element}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Make sure to make the same changes in `gatsby-browser.js`, if you have it.

Now builds are working again and I don't get the SSR error in development either.